# Unable to enable filter in spring mvc interceptor

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I'm writing a multenant application. where we i've following user entity:

```
    @Entity
    @FilterDef(name="byTenantIdFilter", parameters={
    @ParamDef( name="tenantId", type="long")
})
@Filter(name = "byTenantIdFilter", condition = ":tenantId = tenant_id")
    @Table(name = "USER_ACCOUNT")
    public class User {

        @Column(name = "USER_ID")
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        long id;

        @Column(name = "LOGIN_ID", unique = true)
        String loginId;
```

For enabling the filter I've written an interceptor which fetches the session, enables the relevant filter and sets the parameter tenantId.

following is the code of interceptor:

```
public class FilterEnablerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

  @Autowired
  private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
      throws Exception {
    AuthenticatedUser user = (AuthenticatedUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.enableFilter("byTenantIdFilter").setParameter("tenantId", user.getTenantId());
    return true;
  }
```

However, the filter query is not appended to the final query being executed. Probably, because another session being used for fetching the results.

How can I get this done ?

Comment: My progress so far on this:

Comment: My progress so far on this: I've configured hibernate current_session_context_class property as thread. Having this configured I'm able to fetch the session using getCurrentSession() and enable filter as well in interceptor. However, the enabled filter doesn’t get applied on the query executed  via Spring CrudRepository. But it does get applied when I run any criteria query. Any ideas how can I enforce filter over JPA repositories ? Thanks

Comment: Did you find your answer?